# Difference between plot and polar in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've just started learning MATLAB, and the first thing i tried is to plot a spiral,
I found two algorithms on searching,

**PROGRAM 1 -**

```
t = [0:0.1:(100*pi)];
t=sqrt(t);
r=2*t;
polar(t,r);
```

**PROGRAM 2**

```
t = linspace(0,100*pi,1000);
x = t.*cos(t);
y = t.*sin(t);
plot(x,y)
```

Both are working fine, but i would like to to know the basic difference between the `plot()` and `polar()` functions...

Comment: I think it's as simple as: `plot` takes Cartesian coordinates as input, while `polar` takes, well, polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) plots in the Cartesian coordinate system; [`polar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polar.html) plots in the polar one.

A quick search through the documentation or Google would make made this pretty obvious.

Comment: Not to mention, it's clear that you are passing x & y to `plot` and theta and r to `polar`

Comment: The documentation does expect that you understand what polar co-ordinates are so its pretty understandable that you didn't get it from looking at the documentation if your mathematics is a bit weak.

Answer (score 0):

The polar() function as far as I know it does a polar co-ordinate plot, compared to a cartesian co-ordinate plot from plot(). Your spiral should look pretty similar which ever one you use.